# why using @Lock(LockModeType.OPTIMISTIC) in Spring JPA?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, optimistic-locking

To implement an Optimistic lock in Spring JPA, declaring only the @Version Long version field in Entity automatically applies the Optimistic lock function, resulting in an ObjectOptimistic LockingFailureException exception upon concurrent requests.

However, examples show that CustomRepository, which inherited the JpaRepository interface, has seen a lot of code setting @Lock(LockModeType.OPTIMISTIC) on the method.

```java
public interface CustomRepository extends JpaRepository<Entity, Long> {

    @Lock(LockModeType.OPTIMISTIC)
    Optional<Entity> findByShop(Shop shop);
}
```

What are the benefits of applying these settings?
Also, you don't have to apply it, but why do you apply it?

Comment: Have you read documentation? That is described in https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/LockModeType.html. In short `LockModeType.OPTIMISTIC` prevents *Non-repeatable read* phenomena

Comment: The settings in question are for Spring to add a hint to the query. IMO it does nothing that optimistic locking within the entities themselves (a version field of some kind) doesn't do automatically. The notes for requirements on optimistic locking apply to all entities with it set, so it is fairly redundant to add it to the query. How your provider handles it is undefined - it just has to ensure that  transaction changes are isolated and that the version field value from the original query is used when writing out change so it can throw an exception if it has changed since last read.